# How to move the last [0-9]{1,9} cellvalue of a line into the last row (.csv) with bash

Tags: bash, macos, csv, sed, sh

example .csv:

```
"something","31","null","null","null","null",
"something","something","something","142","null","null",
"something","something","24","null","null","null",
```

I wish to have this result:

```
"something","null","null","null","null","31",
"something","something","something","null","null","142",
"something","something","null","null","null","24",
```

How do i move the last [0-9]{1,9} number value with a bash-script into the last cell (if there are only null values in the cells after)?

I tried to do it with sed, but no luck.

Comment: How likely is it that the field values contain the delimiter (`,`)? If it's not likely, `awk` would be your best bet I think. It's a shame that `awk` doesn't support CSV better though (such as quoted fields). (edit: Looks like you can use `-F '","'` as delimiter?)

Comment: Also have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26941

Comment: Try `sed -i.bak -E 's/^(.*)("[0-9]+",)(.*,"null",)$/\1\3\2/' file`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this doesn't guarantee that the last "[0-9]+"  was moved.

Comment: @Kent It does granted the input is in the exact OP format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This short awk script works for the given example:

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' -v pat='^"[0-9]+"$' '{
for(i=NF;i>0;i--)if($i~ pat ){$NF=$i FS;$i="\x98";break}
    sub("\x98,","")
}7' file
```

### short explanation:

This is an interesting problem.

- the `pat` variable stores the regex pattern we want to move to the end
- for each line, we do a loop from the end and check the pattern, so that we can make sure we find the last matched col.
- if we found the col, we set the last field with the matched column with comma. (I noticed you have always an empty field at the end of each row). And we set the value of the col with an invisible value `\x98` so that we can later easily to remove.
- finally, we remove the `"\x98,"` by the `sub()`

### test

```
kent$  cat f
"something","31","null","null","null","null",
"something","something","something","142","null","null",
"something","something","24","null","null","null",

kent$  awk -F',' -v OFS=',' -v pat='^"[0-9]+"$' '{
for(i=NF;i>0;i--)if($i~ pat ){$NF=$i FS;$i="\x98";break}
        sub("\x98,","")
}7' f 
"something","null","null","null","null","31",
"something","something","something","null","null","142",
"something","something","null","null","null","24",
```

Comment: @ChristianFröhlich you are welcome. here at SO, one says thanks by upvoting and accepting the answer.

Comment: Could it be, that if the value is empty "" instead of "null", that it will not work?

Comment: @ChristianFröhlich should work too, if the empty string is wrapped in double-quotes, as other fields.

Comment: its working perfect! Could you give me a hint, what part i need to modify if i only want the numbers from the last x columns moved (more in the front is the id and others numbers i don't want to move). Or should i better open a new question for it?

Comment: @ChristianFröhlich glad to hear that. For your new requirement, you can try to extend `if($i~ pat )` -> `if($i~ pat  &&  i> NF-x)` where the `x` is the range you want. give it a try first with a fixed `x` and corresponding example. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my variant in bash with explanation

```
raw=( $(cat file) )         # load data to raw array
for item in "${raw[@]}"; {  # loop through raw data
    search=${item//[!0-9]/} # this will give only digits
    # if match found remove it from string by change ,"123", to a comma and paste to the end
    [[ $search ]] && item="${item//,\"$search\",/,}\"$search\"," 
    echo $item # print result
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it could work, because i see the script is working, but after a few minutes i needed to cancel it. Maybe its not meant for bigger csv-files.